# I'm working on django framewrk and I'm totaly new to this so I'm uable to to cofigure the static files like css and java, I'm changing the css but no

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGaT.png)

I'm working on django framewrk and I'm totaly new to this so I'm uable to to cofigure the static files like css and java, I'm changing the css but not being update on chrome

Comment: Follow [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#how-to-manage-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)

Answer (score 0):

Django static files can be configured a bit different in development and production modes. Please specify the mode. You can also first check the official django documentation on static files at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the static files on settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

After adding these lines in settings.py, indicating that you will use static files, it is necessary to use the template tag {% load static %} at the beginning of the templates and the tag {% static 'relative_path/staticfile' %} to build the relative path to the static files you need.

Read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#static-files
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#static